# json4s removing keys with value None

Tags: scala, scalatra, json4s

I've been working to return JSON from a Scalatra application using the implicit conversions described in [the docs](http://scalatra.org/2.2/guides/formats/json.html).

I've noticed that keys with empty Options (ie, None) are stripped from the resulting JSON (as opposed to being null, which seems like the expected behaviour)

I have attempted to use implicit conversions to cast `None` to `null`, like:

```
class NoneJNullSerializer extends CustomSerializer[Option[_]](format => (
  {
    case JNull => None
  }, {
    case None => JNull
  }
  ))

protected implicit val jsonFormats: Formats = DefaultFormats.withBigDecimal + new NoneJNullSerializer()
```

however the keys seem to be stripped prior to execution of the custom serializers.

Has anyone found a solution to this?

Note that the solution described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16872893/generating-json-string-using-json4s-from-a-list-containing-some-and-none-values) works in the described case of arrays, however does not seem to work with Maps.

**UPDATE:**
This is the test I have been using:

```
  get("/testJSON") {
    Map(
      "test_key" -> "testValue" ,

      "test_key6" -> "testValue6" ,
      "subObject" -> Map(
        "testNested1" -> "1" ,
        "testNested2" -> 2 ,
        "testArray" -> Seq(1, 2, 3, 4)
      ),
    "testNone" -> None ,
    "testNull" -> null ,
    "testSomeNull" -> Some(null) ,
    "testJNull" -> JNull ,
    "testSomeJNull" -> Some(JNull)
    )
  }
```

and the output I am looking for is

```
{
    "test_key": "testValue",
    "test_some_j_null": null,
    "sub_object": {
        "test_nested1": "1",
        "test_nested2": 2,
        "test_array": [
            1,
            2,
            3,
            4
        ]
    },
    "test_none": null,
    "test_j_null": null,
    "test_key6": "testValue6",
    "test_null": null,
    "test_some_null": null
}
```

I am also using

`protected override def transformResponseBody(body: JValue): JValue = { body.underscoreKeys }`

for underscored keys

Comment: Update version to 3.2.11 and use DefaultFormats.preservingEmptyValues

Answer (score 0):

Using a custom serializer should work also for maps.

```scala
import org.json4s._
import org.json4s.jackson.JsonMethods._

object testNull extends App {

  val data = Map(
    "testNone" -> None,
    "testNull" -> null,
    "testSomeNull" -> Some(null),
    "testJNull" -> JNull,
    "testSomeJNull" -> Some(JNull)
  )

  class NoneJNullSerializer extends CustomSerializer[Option[_]](format => ( {
    case JNull => None
  }, {
    case None => JNull
  }))

  implicit val formats = DefaultFormats + new NoneJNullSerializer

  val ast = Extraction.decompose(data)

  println(pretty(ast))

  //  {
  //    "testSomeJNull" : null,
  //    "testJNull" : null,
  //    "testNone" : null,
  //    "testNull" : null,
  //    "testSomeNull" : null
  //  }

}
```

Comment: Mhmm this is not working still. Perhaps it is a difference between the native and jackson methods.

Comment: Can you create a minimal sample project?

Comment: I will when I have time, however honestly we have started moving away from Scalatra so this is not a priority anymore. When I have a chance I will try to confirm that it is a difference between the implementations, and file a bug report if necessary.

Comment: I simply approach is to use ** implicit val formats = DefaultFormats.preservingEmptyValues**