# Json4s ignoring None fields during seriallization (instead of using 'null')

Tags: json, scala, json4s

I am having a generic json serialization method that uses `json4s`. Unfortunately, it is ignoring fields if the value is `None`. My goal is to have `None` fields be represented with a `null` value. I tried by adding custom serializer for None, but still it is not working.

```
object test extends App {
          class NoneSerializer extends CustomSerializer[Option[_]](format => (
            {     
              case JNull => None
            },
            {
              case None => JNull

            }))

         implicit val f = DefaultFormats + new NoneSerializer

          case class JsonTest(x: String, y: Option[String], z: Option[Int], a: Option[Double], b: Option[Boolean], c:Option[Date], d: Option[Any])

          val v = JsonTest("test", None, None,None,None,None,None); 
println(Serialization.write(v))
}
```

Result from the above code :

```
{"x":"test"}
```

I tried [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16872893/generating-json-string-using-json4s-from-a-list-containing-some-and-none-values) and some others, but is is not solving the issue for case classes

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I assume that you would like to have `None`s serialized to `null` within your JSON. In this case it is sufficient to use `DefaultFormats.preservingEmptyValues`:

```
import java.util.Date
import org.json4s._
import org.json4s.jackson.Serialization

object test extends App {

  implicit val f = DefaultFormats.preservingEmptyValues // requires version>=3.2.11

  case class JsonTest(x: String, y: Option[String], z: Option[Int], a: Option[Double], b: Option[Boolean], c:Option[Date], d: Option[Any])

  val v = JsonTest("test", None, None, None, None, None, None);

  // prints {"x":"test","y":null,"z":null,"a":null,"b":null,"c":null,"d":null}
  println(Serialization.write(v))
}
```

Comment: Which json4s version are you using?

Comment: I am using the version 3.2.10

Comment: Thanks you very much.. it is working after upgrade to 3.2.11 :)

Comment: Do you know how to get this for one field only?

Comment: @RhysBradbury Yes, this is also possible although via a different approach using `FieldSerializer`, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/49759794