# Preserving some null in Json4s

Tags: scala, json4s

I'm trying to marshall a case class in json which is easy enough with json4s.

```
case class container(id: String, `type`: Option[String], things: List[???])
```

Json4s does an excellent job of omitting fields that are null. The issues is I'd like options at the top level of `container` to be preserved but everything in `things` (it's filled with nested options) to preserve these empty options and serve them as Nulls.

The follow question pointed me in the right direction [Json4s ignoring None fields during seriallization (instead of using 'null')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27855934/json4s-ignoring-none-fields-during-seriallization-instead-of-using-null)

But using `implicit val f = DefaultFormats.preservingEmptyValues` targets all of the case classes in scope. Is there anyway I can just target fields within `things`. I can't specifically target fields as there's quite a few and doing this could become unmanageable.

Thanks in advance