# Deserialize a scala list of tuples with option values using json4s

Tags: scala, json4s

I do not know how to use json4s to serialize a list of tuples having option values, so it can deserialize it again. The following example shows the type to (de)serialize:

```
import org.json4s.jackson.Serialization.{read, write}
implicit val formats = DefaultFormats

case class ListTupleOptionValue(l: List[(String, Option[String])])

// Everything is fine having a defined value
val withSomeValueJson = write(ListTupleOptionValue(List(("bKey", Some("bValue")))))
read[ListTupleOptionValue](withSomeValueJson)

// Serialization is faulty or at least deserialization cannot handle it
val withNoneValue = ListTupleOptionValue(List(("bKey", None)))
val withNoneValueJson = write(withNoneValue)// {"l":[{}]} notice the {} empty object definition in the list []

// this works when not having the {} empty object definition
read[ListTupleOptionValue]("{\"l\":[]}")

// this fails with "No usable value for l"
read[ListTupleOptionValue](withNoneValueJson)
```

And the output when trying is

```
No usable value for l
Expected object with 1 element but got JObject(List())
org.json4s.package$MappingException: No usable value for l
Expected object with 1 element but got JObject(List())
at org.json4s.reflect.package$.fail(package.scala:95)
at org.json4s.Extraction$ClassInstanceBuilder.org$json4s$Extraction$ClassInstanceBuilder$$buildCtorArg(Extraction.scala:521)
at org.json4s.Extraction$ClassInstanceBuilder$$anonfun$14.apply(Extraction.scala:541)
at org.json4s.Extraction$ClassInstanceBuilder$$anonfun$14.apply(Extraction.scala:541)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:234)
at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:104)
at org.json4s.Extraction$ClassInstanceBuilder.instantiate(Extraction.scala:529)
at org.json4s.Extraction$ClassInstanceBuilder.result(Extraction.scala:592)
at org.json4s.Extraction$.extract(Extraction.scala:387)
at org.json4s.Extraction$.extract(Extraction.scala:39)
at org.json4s.ExtractableJsonAstNode.extract(ExtractableJsonAstNode.scala:21)
at org.json4s.jackson.Serialization$.read(Serialization.scala:50)
at org.json4s.Serialization$class.read(Serialization.scala:30)
at org.json4s.jackson.Serialization$.read(Serialization.scala:17)
```

Any suggestions about how to make this code example work?
Thanks in advance.

Best regards Trym

Comment: Yeah, I was just testing the same thing that you edited. If you provide `null` instead of `None`, it seems to Serialize it but throws an exception at Deserialize.

Comment: Sorry for editing. I would rather not use null, which is the reason for introducing the Option.

Comment: hey, it's no problem. Can you check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27855934/json4s-ignoring-none-fields-during-seriallization-instead-of-using-null) and see if it works. There are some version constraints so I can't test.

Comment: Great, it solves my problem. When I change the implicit formats value then deserialization can reconstruct my object. So the example code becomes

`implicit val formats = DefaultFormats.preservingEmptyValues
println(write(withNoneValue))
// prints {"l":[{"bKey":null}]}`

Comment: Good to know. Please post it as an answer with the version of json4s and the relevant code so that it can be referenced later by someone who has a similar question.