# How do I serialize one field "preservingEmptyValues" to null using json4s

Tags: json, scala, json4s

I am using json4s.

I am aware that you can "preserve `None` values" of all `Option` members in a type using `DefaultFormats.preservingEmptyValues`.

This has an output like so:

**scala**

```
case class MyType(a: Option[String], b: Option[Int], c: Int)
```

**instance**

```
MyType(None, None, 1)
```

**output**

```
{ "a": null , "b": null , "c": 1 }
```

---

Without `DefaultFormats.preservingEmptyValues` the output is like so:

**scala**

```
case class MyType(a: Option[String], b: Option[Int], c: Int)
```

**instance**

```
MyType(None, None, 1)
```

**output**

```
{ "c": 1 }
```

---

What I would like to do, it keep the default behaviour (removing the property) for one member, say `a` and use the preservingEmptyValues for another, say `b` and have an output like so:

**scala**

```
case class MyType(a: Option[String], b: Option[Int], c: Int)
```

**instance**

```
MyType(None, None, 1)
```

**output**

```
{ "b": null , "c": 1 }
```

---

How does one achieve this using json4s?

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved by implementing a custom serialization function for the `a` field:

```
private def serializeA: PartialFunction[(String, Any), Option[(String, Any)]] = {
  case ("a", x) => x match {
    case None => None
    case _ => Some(("a", x))
  }
}
```

And adding it to the implicit `Formats`:

```
implicit val formats = DefaultFormats.preservingEmptyValues +
                          FieldSerializer[MyType](serializer = serializeA)
```